# Docker run doesn't find files

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, python-poetry

I have a python (with poetry) application that I dockerized, via this file:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

ENV PATH=$PATH:/root/.local/bin

COPY . .
# COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry install
ENTRYPOINT ["poetry", "run", "python", "-m", "my-app"]
```

my application to run via poetry use the following command: `poetry run python -m my_app file`, where 'file' is replaced with the path to the file the application needs.

I run `docker build -t my-app .` And this work.

When i try to run docker: `docker run --rm -it my-app path/to/file.ext` it return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/app/my_app/__main__.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/my_app/__main__.py", line 44, in main
    app.aquire_application()
  File "/app/my_app/app.py", line 37, in aquire_application
    self.config.load_config_from_file(self.config_path)
  File "/app/my_app/frontend/config.py", line 19, in load_config_from_file
    with open(config, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/files/temp/config.yaml'
```

How can i resolve? (Im on Ubuntu)
Thanks

Comment: what is inside my_app , command "RUN poetry install" seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your docker container by running it with an interactive bash script

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash my-app
```

and once you're in the container you can

1. check the filepaths of the files copied by the `COPY` command into the container
2. confirm that poetry was properly installed in the container

Note: if the Dockerfile did not have an `ENTRYPOINT` the syntax would be more like `docker run -it my-app /bin/bash`

Comment: This is useful debugging advice, but it doesn't quite seem like a direct answer to the question.  Because the image puts the command in its `ENTRYPOINT` and expects the `CMD` to be a filename argument, you need a slightly different syntax; `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash my-app`.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, I will correct my answer.  It seems like debugging advice is what is needed here, since we  don't really know what is being copied in from the Dockerfile directory.

Comment: thanks, i check with `bin/bash` and i correct the error. Now it runs a few lines of code and then stops throwing these exceptions: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 30, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`,  `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2,'No such file or ..'))`

Comment: Which is the file that cannot be found? And can you check for that file also using /bin/bash ?

Comment: i think it looks for the file outside the workdir specified in dockerfile, because i dont see '/app' at the beginning of the path.

Comment: but this file is created from poetry...